# How to print the 2 different value using one template

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

In my json data, i am getting `projectName` and `assignedTo` values(it accrues in all data),

example data:

```
  [ {projectName:'project1',assignedTo:'some1'},{projectName:'project2',assignedTo:'some2'}]
```

my template is: (including my confused stuff)

```
<script id="listTemplate" type="text/template">
    <a href="#"><%= projectName === projectName ? projectName : taskStatus%></a>//not works how can i mange?
</script>
```

In my view, i am converting the model `"toJSON()"`, but i am getting the project name alone in the 2 links what i am use.

my request, Is it possible to use a single template to print two different values? - as a first time i need to print project name, later taskStatus with some condition, if so any suggestion please

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve. Can you add some example html output for the JSON string you have?

Comment: The example data that you have above doesn't look like it has the `taskStatus` property. Shouldn't that be `assignedTo` instead in your template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it is constantly printing project name is because, in the template, you have...

```
<a href="#"><%= projectName === projectName ? projectName : taskStatus%></a>
```

`projectName` would always equal to `projectName`. What you'll want to do in this case is, in your Backbone.View, when you serialize the Model to be consumed by the template, you can do this...

```
Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        // An example on how to change the display
        'click button.change-display': 'onChangeDisplayClicked'   
    },
    template: _.template(...),

    // Controls whether project name should be shown or not.
    showProjectName: true,

    onChangeDisplayClicked: function() {
        // Flip the switch
        this.showProjectName = !this.showProjectName;

        // Re-render the View
        this.render();
    },

    serialize: function() {
        // Grab the data from model
        var data = this.model.toJSON();

        // Pass this data to the template to control what to be displayed.
        data.showProjectName = this.showProjectName;
        return data;
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.serialize()));
    }
});
```

... and in your template, you would...

```
<script id="listTemplate" type="text/template">
    <a href="#"><%= showProjectName ? projectName : taskStatu s%></a>
</script>
```